# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have two eclipse plugins. In Plugin A I added Plugin B as dependencies and I am calling the constructor of a class in plugin B from plugin A but I get the error

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

It means the class is available at compile time but not run time, How can I make sure that the class is available at run time as well?

Answer (score 0):

How do you run it ? If you run it in eclipse, make sure plugin B is in list of plugins in `run configurations > Plugins tab` if you run it in eclipse

Edit :
`build.properties` should look like :

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .
```

Comment: I run it from eclipse and plugin B is checked in run configuration -> plugins

Comment: does your plugin B export his package ? (in `manifest.mf`, `runtime` tab  > `exported package`)

Comment: yes it does export the package under Runtime->exported packages

Comment: check your `build.properties` file if you have one

Comment: in build.properties it gives me this warning The plug-in's classpath library '.' does not have a corresponding source build entry

Comment: try removing the `plugin classpath '.'` from the `manifest.mf`, some people seems to correct this error this way